# How to format MySQL query date

Tags: mysql, date

How to format MySQL query date to this format? Current my variable is getting this 08/13/2013 but in my database is 2013-08-13.

```
$sql_stmt = "select * from abs where myname = 'david' and date between '$start' and '$end' order by log_id;";
```

Comment: do you want to format it in the query or afterwards in your php?  Are you worried about future localization?  if so then i would not do it in the query

or perhaps you meant how do you represent $start and $end?

Comment: You'd be better off using parameters in your query instead, that way the date format is irrelevant for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$sql_stmt = "select * from abs where myname = 'david' and date between STR_TO_DATE('$start', '%m/%d/%Y') and STR_TO_DATE('$end', '%m/%d/%Y') order by log_id;";
```

Comment: lol, STR_TO_DATE that's what i was looking for, but couldn't find it in my editor.

Comment: Ya, this is what exactly what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

see the examples in the date format section [HERE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

UPDATE
you can format it almost anyway, check this [**SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac953/2)

Comment: just configure it the way you want, try this:`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dates, '%Y-%m-%d') FROM datetbl;`

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the output string into variable date format and then compare it.

```
$sql_stmt = "select *,DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d/%c/%Y') as date1 
from abs 
where 
myname = 'david' 
and date1 between '$start' and '$end' 
order by log_id;";
```

Answer (score 0):

We have

```
mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT('1997-10-04 22:23:00', '%W %M %Y');
        -> 'Saturday October 1997'
```

and we can possibly adapt your solution to

```
$sql_stmt = "select * from abs where myname = 'david' 
          and DATE_FORMAT(date, '%W %M %Y') 
          between STR_TO_DATE('$start', '%m/%d/%Y') 
          and STR_TO_DATE('$end', '%m/%d/%Y') order by log_id;";
```